# Update table with join and where

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I have the following tables

**table1**

```
ID_DW   code   descr
-------------------
abcd    123    test
```

**table2**

```
ID     name    t
--------------------
123    test    null
```

I have to copy `table1.id_dw` into `table2.t` column every time `table1.code = table2.id and table1.descr = table2.name`.

My query is the following:

```
UPDATE table2
SET table2.t = table1.id_dw
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.code = table2.id AND table1.descr = table2.name
```

but the results are all null.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Your SQL works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=08b84862207657bbf17cb4b8a0f022bc). Take the time to produce us a full [mre].

Comment: The logic looks correct.  Maybe your data has trailing whitespace?

Comment: Trailing whitespaces are ignored for comparison purposes though, @TimBiegeleisen . `'abcd    ' = 'abcd'` would resolve the TRUE. *Leading* whitespaces, on the other hand, are not.

Comment: Didn't know that, good point.

Comment: there are any whitespaces, strings are identical..

Comment: Then the above would work, as I demonstrate. Provide us with a [mre] as what you have given us works fine.

Comment: As @Larnu said, can you provide how are you creating these sample tables? The update returns some error or it just doesn't update the tables? The only choice why it doesn't work is what I said in my answer, but it would return an error => https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c97bf5d64835ff2403943f38baf8c2e6

Answer (score 1):

> results are all null.

This could mean multiple things:

- No rows are matching the `JOIN` conditions (most likely).
- The `id_dw` values are all `NULL`.
- Multiple rows are matching the `JOIN` conditions for each row being updated and the "chosen" row has `NULL` in `id_dw`.

There may be other reasons as well, but I would start with the first.

The `code` and `id` columns look like they are integers.  Those should match directly.  So, investigate the `name`/`descr` columns.  Does this return any rows?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.code = table2.id AND table1.descr = table2.name;
```

Does this return any rows?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.code = table2.id ;
```

Does this return any rows?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 JOIN
     table2
     ON table1.code = table2.id ;
WHERE table1.descr LIKE '%' + table2.name + '%' OR
      table2.name LIKE '%' + table1.descr + '%';
```

In other words, you are going to need to investigate the data to see why matches that you think should work are not matching.  One common problem are "hidden" characters (such as leading spaces) and look-alike characters.